# Can I use SurveyMonkey to record clicks, separately from sending survey mails?

Tags: surveymonkey

I want to send out a survey mail that looks like this:

```
 Dear <customer_id>

 [intro]

 <a href='foo'>click here for yes</a>
 <a href='bar'>click here for no</a>
```

Then I want to be able to get data out that looks like this (or similar):

```
customer_id,response
123,yes
124,
125,no
```

I need to use a third-party system to generate and send the emails.

My question is: can I use the SurveyMonkey API only to generate the links and collect the data? I can't use their system to send the mails, but it would be great to use SurveyMonkey for the link tracking and data aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurveyMonkey does not offer a way to generate links that represent answers to questions. The third-party application would need to use the [response creation API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses) to generate responses, and map third-party links to the appropriate answer during generation.